# How can I get the results from a onclick event render in a new page and window in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, window.open

I'm trying to have the results from a onClick event render in a new page and window. I am having a couple issues.

I tried wrapping my rendering of the Pdfs component in a window.open function. This would be too easy and does not work at all.
I tried adding the states that I needed to the history.push function

```
 handleContract = (id) => {
  API.openRow(id)
  .then(res => {
    const pdfs = res.data;
    this.setState({pdfs});
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/pdf',
      state: { labels:this.state.labels,
        contracts:this.state.contracts, 
        pdfs:this.state.pdfs }
    })
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

I get Cannot read property 'map' of undefined on the /pdf page

Here is where the OnClick event is happening in child component and contains the data needed for the /pdf page.

```
const SearchResults = props => (
  <tbody>

{ props.contracts.map((contract, i) => (

<tr key={i} data-id={contract.Id}  
    onClick={() => {props.handleContract(contract.Fields.filter(field => field.DataField==="IDXT001").map(field => field.DataValue))}}
    className="clickable-row"
    target="_blank">{contract.Fields.map( docs =>  
    <td key={docs.Id}><span id={docs.DataField}>{docs.DataValue}</span></td>)}
</tr>))}

  </tbody>
)
```

On the Parent page..

```
  class SearchPage extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    labels: [],
    contracts: [],
    formValues:"",
    pdfs:[],
    id:"",
  };
  this.onClick = this.handleContract.bind(this);
}

<SearchResults 
 labels={this.state.labels}
 contracts={this.state.contracts} 
 pdfs={this.state.pdfs}
 handleContract={this.onClick}
 />
```

My app.js file

```
 <BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Search} />
    <Route exact path='/pdf' component={Pdf} />
    <Footer />
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

And my Pdf component..

```
  const Pdfs = props => (

    <div className="container">
       <div className="row">
         {props.pdfs.map(contract => 
           <div className="col-sm-4" key={contract.Id}>
              <div className="card scroll">
                <div className="card-body">
            <p><i className="fas fa-file-pdf fa-lg"></i> <a href= 
          {"http://api/document/" + contract.DocImage.sfScanIndex}
          className="link"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >{contract.DocImage.sfFilename}</a></p>
          <p>{contract.Fields.map(docs => 
          <div><h6 className="card-title">{docs.DisplayName}:</h6>
            <p className="card-text">{docs.DataValue}</p>
            <hr/>
          </div>)}
            </p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>)}
 </div>
```

)

Here is a console log of the props in pdfs after I click the tabel row...

```
   {match: {…}, location: {…}, history: {…}, staticContext: undefined}
history: {length: 36, action: "PUSH", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}
location:
    hash: ""
    key: "f8b43j"
    pathname: "/pdf"
    search: ""
    state:
        contracts: [{…}]
        labels: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
        pdfs: Array(7)
            0: {Id: 0, Fields: Array(12), DocImage: {…}}
            1: {Id: 1, Fields: Array(12), DocImage: {…}}
            2: {Id: 2, Fields: Array(12), DocImage: {…}}
            3: {Id: 3, Fields: Array(12), DocImage: {…}}
            4: {Id: 4, Fields: Array(12), DocImage: {…}}
            5: {Id: 5, Fields: Array(12), DocImage: {…}}
            6: {Id: 6, Fields: Array(12), DocImage: {…}}
        length: 7
    __proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
match: {path: "/pdf", url: "/pdf", isExact: true, params: {…}}
staticContext: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

I would like the /pdf page to also open in a separate window. To allow the "/" page to remain the same. I tried adding a target="_blank" to the row that is being clicked.

Comment: check if Fields property exists on contract object

Comment: Api is working correctly. I can get the Pdf component to render on the "/" page with the correct data. Just not on "/pdf"

Comment: log the `props` object in `Pdfs` function and see if `pdfs` property exists. The Error says, Can not read property map of undefined.

Comment: This is in the props in the pdfs function and I click the tr. location:
hash: ""
key: "f8b43j"
pathname: "/pdf"
search: ""
state:
contracts: Array(1)
0: {Id: 0, Fields: Array(6), DocImage: {…}}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
labels: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
pdfs: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object

Comment: replace `props.pdfs.map` with `props.location.state.pdfs` in Pdfs component. or pass only `location.state.pdfs` as prop to Pdfs component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prop `pdfs` exits inside `props.location.state.pdfs`. Either replace `props.pdfs.map` with `props.location.state.pdfs` in Pdfs component or extract pass only pdfs as prop to Pdfs component

Comment: Perfect. thanks for pointing that out. Do you know how I can have that /pdf open in a new window?

Comment: Opening the pdf in a new window works fine, by including a target_blank in the "a" tag in the pdfs page. I just want to know how to have the pathway "/pdfs" open in a new tab instead of going to the new pathway on the same page.